# Android drawing on a bitmap on a canvas after pinch zoom

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawing, scaling

I have a custom drawing view which basically draws a bitmap on a canvas and then I can paint on the bitmap using a flood fill algorithm. I'm trying to implement a pinch zoom feature. After the user zooms, I want them to be able to draw in the zoomed position as well. This is my code for onDraw():

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,mScaleX,mScaleY);
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

onTouchEvent():

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
//detect user touch

    if(event.getPointerCount()>1) {
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                final Point p1 = new Point();
                float x0=touchX-mScaleX;
                float y0=touchY-mScaleY;
                x0=x0*mScaleFactor;
                y0=y0*mScaleFactor;
                x0+=mScaleX;
                y0+=mScaleY;
                p1.x = (int) x0;
                p1.y = (int) y0;
                Log.d("Pixel coordinates",p1.x+" "+p1.y);
                Log.d("touch co-ordinates", touchX+" "+touchY);
                Log.d("pivot points", mScaleX+" "+mScaleY);
                Log.d("Scalefactor", Float.toString(mScaleFactor));
                int pixel = canvasBitmap.getPixel(p1.x, p1.y);
                prev_bitmap = canvasBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                bitMapStack.push(prev_bitmap);
                floodFill(canvasBitmap, p1, pixel, paintColor);
                break;
            default:
                return false;

        }
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

ScaleListener:

```
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        mScaleX=detector.getFocusX();
        mScaleY=detector.getFocusY();
        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));


        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to zoom, my app fails and I get the message:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.dhruv.coloringbook, PID: 14161
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()
                                                                                    at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:1429)

I'm not sure why this is happening because getPixel is not even supposed to be getting called during a scale gesture, and I also don't know why my y coordinate is out of bounds for the bitmap. How could I fix this/are there better implementations for the same thing?

EDIT: Full stack trace:
    09-25 16:44:48.456 16730-16730/com.example.dhruv.coloringbook D/Pixel coordinates: 1080 2768
09-25 16:44:48.457 16730-16730/com.example.dhruv.coloringbook D/touch co-ordinates: 106.0 724.0
09-25 16:44:48.457 16730-16730/com.example.dhruv.coloringbook D/pivot points: 651.0 864.5
09-25 16:44:48.457 16730-16730/com.example.dhruv.coloringbook D/Scalefactor: 2.2871902
09-25 16:44:48.457 16730-16730/com.example.dhruv.coloringbook E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
09-25 16:44:48.457 16730-16730/com.example.dhruv.coloringbook E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
09-25 16:44:48.459 16730-16730/com.example.dhruv.coloringbook E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: y must be < bitmap.height()
                                                                                      at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkPixelAccess(Bitmap.java:1429)
                                                                                      at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixel(Bitmap.java:1378)
                                                                                      at com.example.dhruv.coloringbook.DrawingView.onTouchEvent(DrawingView.java:179)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9297)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2769)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9517)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4242)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4108)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3799)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3681)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3856)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3707)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3673)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3681)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3654)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5969)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5869)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6072)
                                                                                      at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
                                                                                      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                                      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: Post full stack traces, so we can see the logic flow of the crash.  A partial stack trace isn't enough to fully tell what's happening, especially when it crashes in framework code.

Comment: Edited to add the full trace

Answer (score 0):

So imagine that you're doing a pinch to zoom.  YOu put down finger 1.  We treat this as a down.  YOu put down finger 2-  now we see 2 pointers down.  We left up finger 2.  We now have 1 pointer down again.  We lift up finger 1-  we get an action up, but we only see 1 pointer down (because the other one was already lifted).  So we treat it as a single finger up.  To prevent this, you need to track if there were ever two fingers down in this touch.

That explains why getPixel was called in a zoom. As for why the crash-  the scaled pixel position is bigger than the canvas bitmap.  Fixing the above issue may or may not fix it, as I don't know what logic you use to size/resize the canvasBitmap.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the pointers! I'll fix that and try again. For the scaling position, I was using the advice from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366418/after-canvas-zoom-with-pivot-point-x-and-y-coordinates-are-wrong?noredirect=1&lq=1